# How to use VBA to change if an Excel file is visible (minimized) based on changes to the grand totals in a pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a live report in Excel that shows if cranes are currently delayed. What I would like to do, by using VBA, is to make it so that when a crane either starts a delay, or ends one, the file will go from being minimized to being expanded so that a user can be signalled for when a crane has gone on delay. I would also like this to only occur for the cranes that are present within the table after being filtered.

I have attached an image of the data along with the relevant filter for cranes.
[Crane Delay Data with Crane Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a1dQ.png)

My thinking was to scan the Grand Total column, and if the value has changed from being empty to having a figure greater than 0 (and vice versa) to trigger a Macro that will make the file visible.

If possible, what code would I need to use and how would I go about doing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: it is possible and not even big in terms of code. But usually things popping up violently are not nice to the user, probably a different type of notification (like an email) would suit better. Also, how do the data change in the spreadsheet (I mean, if user A has the spreadsheet minimized, what process makes the number change so that user A will see the spreadsheet maximized)?

Comment: Data is refreshed every minute via an external data connection to a SQL Server database. Although it is a violent method of notifying someone of a delay, the purpose is so that the user can be notified instantly of a specific delay beginning, so that they can react accordingly. Unfortunately the users are not likely to have their emails open throughout their shift, and also comment that screen space is an issue when controlling the operation (hence the need for this file to expand when a delay on a specific QC that the user is responsible for has either begun or ended). Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I have come up with a solution. Please leave a comment if you want me to talk through it. Code is below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableAfterValueChange(ByVal TargetPivotTable As PivotTable, ByVal TargetRange As Range)

End Sub

Public Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim wsBackup As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    Dim rngPivot As Range
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim strCrane As String
    Dim sValues As Variant

    sValues = ArrayListOfSelectedAndVisibleSlicerItems("Slicer_QC1")

    'Change to suit
    Set pt = Me.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    'Where has a copy of table been saved?
    Set wsBackup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Copy")

    Set rngPivot = pt.DataBodyRange
    'How many columns?
    lastCol = rngPivot.Columns.Count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Check each cell in last column/grand total
    For Each c In rngPivot.Columns(lastCol).Cells
        'What item is this?
        strCrane = c.Offset(0, -lastCol).Value


        'Escape clause
        If strCrane = "Grand Total" Then Exit For

        If c.Value = 0 Then
            'Use a function that won't throw an error
            'Note we add 1 to account for row labels
            If WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(wsBackup.Columns(1 + lastCol), _
                wsBackup.Range("A:A"), strCrane) <> 0 Then
                If IsInArray(strCrane, sValues) = True Then

                    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
                    MsgBox strCrane & " has ended a delay" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "(Minimise Excel after using file)"
                
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf c.Value > 0 Then
            If WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(wsBackup.Columns(1 + lastCol), _
                wsBackup.Range("A:A"), strCrane) = 0 Then
                If IsInArray(strCrane, sValues) = True Then
                    
                    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
                    MsgBox strCrane & " has started a delay" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "(Minimise Excel after using file)"
                
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    'Save our new backup
    wsBackup.Cells.Clear
    pt.TableRange2.Copy
    wsBackup.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Clean up
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function ArrayListOfSelectedAndVisibleSlicerItems(MySlicerName As String) As Variant
    'This function returns an array of the limited set of items in Slicer A
    'Limitation is due to both:
    '(1) direct selection of items by user in slicer A
    '(2) selection of items in slicer B which in consequence limits the number of items in slicer A

    Dim ShortList() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer: i = 0 'for iterate

    Dim sC As SlicerCache
    Dim sI As SlicerItem 'for iterate

    Set sC = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(MySlicerName)
    For Each sI In sC.SlicerItems
        If sI.Selected = True Then
            ' Debug.Print sI.Name
            ReDim Preserve ShortList(i)
            ShortList(i) = sI.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next sI
    ArrayListOfSelectedAndVisibleSlicerItems = ShortList
End Function

Private Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1
End Function
```